# Iterating over nested yaml values in terraform

Tags: terraform, yaml

I have the following config

```yaml
config:
  groups:
    group1:
      capabilities:
        - create
        - read
        - update
      members:
      - robert@gmail.com
      - paul@gmail.com
    group2:
      capabilities:
        - create
        - list
      members:
        - peter@gmail.com
    group3:
      capabilities:
        - read
        - list
      members:
        - john@gmail.com
```

So I want to create a set of `vault` identities in `terraform`

```
resource "vault_identity_entity" "this" {
  for_each = ?1

  name     = each.key
}
```

How should I iterate (or should I say parse the `yaml` config) so that the `vault_identity_entity` is created for everything under `config.groups.*.members` , i.e. for all the email entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for_each` accepts a set of strings, so you can use:

```
resource "vault_identity_entity" "this" {
  for_each = toset(flatten(values(local.config.config.groups)[*].members))

  name     = each.key
}
```